# Sorting algorithm in OpenOffice calc

Tags: python, algorithm, sorting

I'm having a really long day, the culmination of which is a dumb moment trying to sort a list of strings.  Calc sorts them like this:

```
0DCv6UlY6T0
0ITZEBZrwMk
1062VEX2EfI
2jk7hilGMs0
2lZVu3haI6A
3f8s3KbFQ0Q
3hB09daYLmk
43Erj3qFxxo
6lj33w3YoOw
7jiNQnkfx0k
7TSMj6g3UoE
7Wba8IUk6v8
9hbG9dS7zl0
ALThJiGFBSc
by_VzOiPhZM
Ce250P1xep0
Cgx6DV6RJg8
d5dDgLRd1-o
DnyzZwaYDXE
dO5KLh2er4E
```

This isn't quite what I expected.  Look at the last 3 values.  Shouldn't the entry starting with a capital D come before the ones starting with lowercase d (or the other way around)?  Why does it come *between* the lowercase d entries?

Funnily, command line `sort` in Linux does things the same way.  Can somebody explain the logic behind such sorting?  I need to replicate it (or reproduce it in Python, if it's already implemented somewhere).

Comment: It likely just disregards the case, and treats `D` and `d` as the same letter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For replication:

```
   data = [  "abc", "aBB", "abD", "Aac", "AAb", "ABc", "ABa" ]
   print sorted(data, key = lambda item: item.upper())
```

The trick is to provide the `key` argument. This function is applied to the list items, and the result is used for comparisions during the sort.

Answer (score 4):

It's because of locale. See the difference between:

```
sort inputfile
```

and with (what you probably want):

```
LANG="C" sort inputfile
```

output of second command:

```
0DCv6UlY6T0
0ITZEBZrwMk
1062VEX2EfI
2jk7hilGMs0
2lZVu3haI6A
3f8s3KbFQ0Q
3hB09daYLmk
43Erj3qFxxo
6lj33w3YoOw
7TSMj6g3UoE
7Wba8IUk6v8
7jiNQnkfx0k
9hbG9dS7zl0
ALThJiGFBSc
Ce250P1xep0
Cgx6DV6RJg8
DnyzZwaYDXE
by_VzOiPhZM
d5dDgLRd1-o
dO5KLh2er4E
```

Answer (score 2):

Whether capitals are lexicographically distinct from lower-case letters depends on the locale (specifically LC_COLLATE), which explains the command line sort program (and ls and ...), and presumably also Openoffice.

E.g.

```
$ cat test 
Abc
aabc
$ sort test 
aabc
Abc
$ LC_COLLATE=C sort test 
Abc
aabc
```

Comment: There's an option in OpenOffice to do a case-sensitive search.  It seems to be ignoring it.  In that case it's a bug, right?